# Skype Microphone voice too quiet

Tags: audio, skype, microphone

Firstly, I would like to specify that my problem only exists in Skype, I have tried Audio Recorder, Teamspeak, RaidCall and in those applications my microphone works very fine.

However in Skype, the same microphone choosed and audio volume is maxed in Skype settings but my voice is too quiet to be heard when I speak. It has been like that for a week now.

Yesterday, after the skype update, it has been fixed for a day but i have the same problem again today. My Realtek is also up to date.

UPDATE:
I realized that I can solve it till I restart my computer by deleting my audio drivers and reinstalling but I have to do that everyday to make it work.

Anyone has any solution for this or got the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in *Tools -> Options -> Audio Settings -> Microphone* which input you have selected? You may notice there's a little check-box below that says "Automatically adjust microphone settings".

Try with that both checked or unchecked, and another thing you can try is to experiment with the settings while you are in the middle of a call, I think you can change or adjust audio input and output during a video or audio call too.

Comment: I tried both actually I also tried the solution given here http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-auto-logs-off/m-p/938210/highlight/true#M69026 , I tried to reinstall skype and tried to use skype app for windows 8 non worked for me